# I lost map zoom by using directions with sencha touch

Tags: google-maps, sencha-touch, sencha-touch-2

i have a view to show a map with the direction between start and end point.

the direction is ok, but i lost the zoom factor and the zoom is 0.

when i delete 'directionsDisplay.setMap(gmap);', the zoom factor is ok.

here i read to set a timeout, but i don't know on which place i have to do this...?
http://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?193567-2.0.1-Map-Directions-Not-Zooming-to-correct-level-or-not-showing

here is my code:

```
Ext.define("ElectroRadar.view.map.Start", {
extend: 'Ext.Map',
xtype: 'maptest',

config: {

    title: 'Karte',
    iconCls: 'maps',

 id:'menuMap2',

          mapOptions: {
                            zoom : 15,
                            mapTypeId : google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
                            navigationControl: true,
                            navigationControlOptions: {
                                            style: google.maps.NavigationControlStyle.DEFAULT
            }

      },


    listeners: [
        {
            fn: 'onMapMaprender',
            event: 'maprender'
        }
    ]
},

onMapMaprender: function(map, gmap, options) {
    var start = '';
  navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(position) {
            var start = new google.maps.LatLng(position.coords.latitude,position.coords.longitude);
            var end = new google.maps.LatLng(54.5625461,9.9488523); 

            var directionsDisplay = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer();
            var directionsService = new google.maps.DirectionsService();

            directionsDisplay.setMap(gmap);

            var request = {
                origin:start, 
                destination:end,
                travelMode: google.maps.DirectionsTravelMode.DRIVING
            };

            directionsService.route(request, function(response, status) {                                                   
                if (status == google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK) {
                    directionsDisplay.setDirections(response);
                }
            });
    });                                      
}});
```

what can i change in my code, that a zoom is used for the best directions view?

here you can see it:
http://wachtelborn.net/_ansicht/event/mobile/4/

navigate to 'karte'

Answer (score 0):

Right after directionsDisplay.setDirections():

```
if (status == google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK) {
    directionsDisplay.setDirections(response);
}
```